# The view form.views.form_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I try to learn about form validation and this ValueError appears , here is my views.py and forms.py file

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

class SignUp(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField(label='User Name', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='PassWord')
    botcatcher = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput, validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import SignUp
# Create your views here.

# 127.0.0.1/ 
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')

# 127.0.0.1/form
def form_view(request):
    if request.method == ('POST'):
        form = SignUp(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
             
          
    else:
        form = SignUp()
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'signupForm' : form})
```

Comment: what should happen when the form isn't valid?

Comment: The error already tells you what's wrong. You are returning nothing in some cases (looking at your code: in the case the form isn't valid), instead of always returning an `HttpResponse` as you are supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If form is not `valid` there is no `else`  part in your  `views.py` that is why it throws error since you have not returned `HttpResponse` object if form validation `fails`. So please add `HttpResponse` in your `views.py` if form validation fails.

```
# 127.0.0.1/form
def form_view(request):
    if request.method == ('POST'):
        form = SignUp(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(/) # render(...) whatever you wanted if form validation fails
         
      
    else:
        form = SignUp()
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'signupForm' : form})
```